# What does the term “nontrivial rotation” mean?

Tags: terminology

The paper “Gimli: a cross-platform permutation” contains the following information:

> *Occasionally* (after rounds 24, 20, 16, etc.) Gimli adds an asymmetric constant to entry 0 of the first row. This constant has many bits set (it is essentially the golden ratio `0x9e3779b9`, as used in TEA), and is not close to any of its nontrivial rotations (never fewer than 12 bits different)

What does the term “nontrivial rotation” mean? How to distinguish a “nontrivial” rotation from a “trivial” one?

Comment: after rotation that you got the same result? as 32 rotation in 32 bit integer?

Comment: @kelalaka: Then does a 32-bit integer 2863311530 have 16 trivial and 16 nontrivial rotations (assuming that the maximum is 32)? But an integer 1 will have only one trivial rotation (at 32)? And for an integer 0, all rotations are trivial?

Comment: Here instead of trivial I prefer identity rotation, if you consider the rotations as a family. I would not call anything other then the 32 rotation since other definitions relay on data as 101010...01010 or 000..000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trivial rotation is one where the input to the rotation is equal to the output (hence the rotation is equal to the identity function). Rotating by a multiple of $n$ is a trivial rotation for all $n$ bit values. Note that for certain values other trivial rotations may exist. See below for the values of the (right) rotations of `0x9e3779b9` ($n = 32$) and the amount of different bits for each:

```
0:  0x9e3779b9 (0  bits different)
1:  0xcf1bbcdc (14 bits different)
2:  0x678dde6e (22 bits different)
3:  0x33c6ef37 (18 bits different)
4:  0x99e3779b (12 bits different)
5:  0xccf1bbcd (14 bits different)
6:  0xe678dde6 (18 bits different)
7:  0x733c6ef3 (16 bits different)
8:  0xb99e3779 (14 bits different)
9:  0xdccf1bbc (12 bits different)
10: 0x6e678dde (16 bits different)
11: 0x3733c6ef (16 bits different)
12: 0x9b99e377 (16 bits different)
13: 0xcdccf1bb (14 bits different)
14: 0xe6e678dd (12 bits different)
15: 0xf3733c6e (16 bits different)
16: 0x79b99e37 (20 bits different)
17: 0xbcdccf1b (16 bits different)
18: 0xde6e678d (12 bits different)
19: 0xef3733c6 (14 bits different)
20: 0x779b99e3 (16 bits different)
21: 0xbbcdccf1 (16 bits different)
22: 0xdde6e678 (16 bits different)
23: 0x6ef3733c (12 bits different)
24: 0x3779b99e (14 bits different)
25: 0x1bbcdccf (16 bits different)
26: 0x8dde6e67 (18 bits different)
27: 0xc6ef3733 (14 bits different)
28: 0xe3779b99 (12 bits different)
29: 0xf1bbcdcc (18 bits different)
30: 0x78dde6e6 (22 bits different)
31: 0x3c6ef373 (14 bits different)
```

Comment: Does the term “asymmetric” in this context mean that for a particular $n$-bit value $X$ there will be at least 1 bit of difference between $X$ and $X$ rotated by any number in the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n-2, n-1\}$?

Answer (score -3):

in simple terms a rotation where a rotation is performed on a figure such that the  figure maps   itself back to its original position  such that the rotation is greater than 0° but less than 360°.

Comment: You can add your website link to your personal info. It is better suited there. The rotation is not angular, it is a rotation of integers

Comment: It's spam: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=rightfamilydentalny